# How can I scrape something that appears on the site, but not on the source page of the website?

Tags: scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to scrape a betting website for all their live events and corresponding odds.

I verified the xpath response in Scrapy Shell, all great, but when I wanted to extract the text from the span tag there was none. I then checked the website source page and indeed, there was no text in the node I was trying to scrape. Here is the code from the source page:

```html
<div class="sports-body" data-bind="visible: anyNonStarred">
                                        <div class="league-title js-toggle-region">
                                            <span class="icon arrow grey" data-bind="css:{selected:isExpanded}"></span>
                                            <!-- ko if: $data.flagName && $data.flagName() -->
                                            <span data-bind="attr:{'class':cssmap('flag flag-' + flagName())}"></span>
                                            <!-- /ko -->
                                            <span data-bind="text:name"></span>
                                        </div>
```

Is this beacause the site is using JavaScript? And if so, how can I scrape it? Can Scrapy handle it?

The url is: https://ro.betano.com/live/

Comment: This is happening because the websites uses a BackEnd language, like PHP, C#, etc. You can read about that [here](http://www.cellbiol.com/bioinformatics_web_development/chapter-4-adding-a-dynamic-layer-introducing-the-php-programming-language/dynamic-web-pages-with-php-a-simple-yet-useful-example/).

Comment: Ok, so does that mean that the site is unscrapable? Thank you for the link!

Comment: You should be able to get data inserted from Backend. If it's not there, be sure that you're looking at the correct place.

Comment: See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html

Answer (score 0):

Those missing items are loading from scripts means it's from a dynamic request. You cant get those elements from the page source. You should try some dynamic scraping tools for that purpose.

1. Scrapy and Splash are the nest combo you can work with. ([Check this](https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2015/03/02/handling-javascript-in-scrapy-with-splash)).
2. Try Selenium, using selenium we are making the exact same approach does the browser make. if we can spot the elements in the browser inspect section, we can definitely get it in selenium.